# Typing reducer with redux-actions library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-actions

I'm struggling to type the second argument, action, of my reducer now that I use `createAction` from the `redux-actions` library.

Part of my reducer code is as follows

```
type AddItems = 'addItems';
const AddItems: AddItems = 'addItems';

interface AddItemAction extends Action<CartItem> {
    type: AddItems;
}

export const addItems = createAction<CartItem>(AddItems);

type RemoveItem = 'removeItem';
const RemoveItem: RemoveItem = 'removeItem';

interface RemoveItemAction extends Action<number> {
    type: RemoveItem;
}

export const removeItem = createAction<number>(RemoveItem);

export type ShoppingCartActions = AddItemAction | RemoveItemAction;

export const shoppingCartActions = {
    addItems,
    removeItem
};

export default function shoppingCartReducer(state: ShoppingCartStore = shoppingCartInitialState, action: ShoppingCartActions) {
    const { type, payload } = action;    
    switch (type) {
        case AddItems:
           return {
            cartItems: [
                ...state.cartItems.filter(cartItem => cartItem.item.id !== payload!.item.id),
                payload
            ]               
           };
        case RemoveItem:
           return {
               cartItems: [
                   ...state.cartItems.filter(cartItem => cartItem.item.id !== payload)
               ]
           };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I access a property on `payload` in my reducer it thinks that the property must exist for each case. For example, in the case of `addItems` I access `payload.item` but typescript complains because it also looks for `item` to be on the type number coming from `RemoveItemAction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't have the redux or redux-actions libaries installed locally so I can't be 100% sure if this answer is correct; please test it.

---

`ShoppingCartActions` is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) where `type` is the discriminant property.  You are expecting TypeScript to act as advertised when you check the discriminant: it should automatically narrow the type of the `action` variable to the appropriate consituent of the union.

Unfortunately, you are destructuring `action` into two variables, `type` and `payload` like this:

```
const { type, payload } = action;
```

*and the compiler does not understand that the types of `type` and `payload` are correlated.*  That is, if you narrow `type` from `AddItems | RemoveItem` to `AddItems`, the compiler does *not* automatically narrow `payload` from `CartItem | number` to `CartItem`.  Even though *we* know that this must be the case, the compiler is not as smart as us, and the [heuristics](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) it uses to analyze the control flow are not up to the task of understanding "entangled variables" like this.

You are [not](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10065) the [first](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10846) person [to](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14630) run [into](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10976) this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23613).  The comments by the language designers in those issues are generally something like "it would be nice if the compiler could do this for you, but it would be very expensive to implement and lead to poor compiler performance".

---

The easiest fix in this case is to use discriminated unions the way that TypeScript intends: *do not destructure `action`*.  Use direct property accesses on `action` instead:

```
export default function shoppingCartReducer(
  state: ShoppingCartStore = shoppingCartInitialState, 
  action: ShoppingCartActions
) {
  // switch on property of action
  switch (action.type) {
    case AddItems:
      return {
        // action.payload is now CartItem
        cartItems: [              
          ...state.cartItems.filter(
            cartItem => cartItem.item.id !== action.payload!.item.id
          ),
          action.payload
        ]
      };
    case RemoveItem:
      // action.payload is now number
      return {
        cartItems: [
          ...state.cartItems.filter(
            cartItem => cartItem.item.id !== action.payload
          )
        ]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This should now work as intended, I think.

---

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Great answer. Really appreciate the detailed answer but tagging all the related github issues might be a little over the type. Didn't know what the problem was so didn't know what the google. You're explanation clear it all up!